# Using tf.estimator.Estimator with save_checkpoint_steps leads to Tensorboard warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

When using `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(...)` with an `tf.estimator.Estimator` configurated with `tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=10, ...)`, a `CheckpointSaverHook` will be created automatically. This `CheckpointSaverHook` will save the graph and graph_def to the summary writer every time it is triggered (see [CheckpointSaverHook.before_run](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/36b83257287148ddb4aab02c641d1ac9e192a136/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py#L440)).

Basic code example:

```py
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn, model_dir, params,
    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_steps=100, 
        save_summary_steps=100
    )
)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_fn)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(eval_fn)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

When starting Tensorboard on the written summary, it will output a hundreds of warnings because of multiple graph defs in the summary which I guess slows it down a lot on startup:

```
W0117 18:47:30.278879 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W0117 18:47:30.279753 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.
```

I see there might be issues when using multiple graphs, but for a single graph this seems unpracticable. Are we using the estimator correctly here and is this behavior intended? Do we need to write a custom hook instead in order to prevent this from happening?

Thanks for your advice!

Edit: Due to suggestions from comments there is an issue now:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17272

Comment: Maybe your `model_dir` already contains a lot of previous metadata / summaries?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot There is exactly one events summary in that folder. The problem is that the linked CheckpointSaverHook writes the graph every time it outputs a checkpoint.

Comment: Can you try using tf.estimator.RunConfig?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot I don't see what you mean. I am already using the RunConfig, that is why train_and_evaluate automatically creates the CheckpointSaverHook which causes the problem, but which we want for creating checkpoints (except the duplicate graph def).

Comment: In your post you say that you use the one from tf.contrib.learn, I suggested you try the one from tf.estimator

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot I guess that won't change a thing, because the RunConfig is just a container for the config and doesn't create the hooks itself (see [estimator.py:818](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/36b83257287148ddb4aab02c641d1ac9e192a136/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L818) for how it is evaluated). Still it would be better to use this one to get rid of the contrib package. Updated the code example accordingly.

Comment: You should maybe submit a GitHub issue, as this doesn't seem like the intended behavior.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Is there a github issue about this?

Comment: Now it does: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17272